# Keep selected drop down menu option visible after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, reload

I have an error message that only shows if the audio file isn't found. If it is found then people see an ON button. The error message can be clicked on to reload the page. I want it to remain on the current active drop down menu page. Right now it makes you reselect an option from the drop down menu.

```js
<!--I coult not get the page to display properly by putting the JS code here. That is why it's in the html field-->
```

```css
<!--I coult not get the page to display properly by putting the css code here. That is why it's in the html field-->
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<style>
.down {
  font: bold 15px Arial;
  background-color:  red;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 3px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
</style>




<style>

select {
  border: 50px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #12f3fd;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
 
  
  
  *background: Black;
  
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
   <select name="stations" id="station" style="font-size:25px;" align="center">
    <option>Select a Opton</option>
    <option value="1">What you see if audio file was found</option>
    <option value="2">What you see if audio file was not found</option>
   
    
  </select>
</div>
<div class="st hidden" id="st1">
    <p>
    <audio id="audio1" src="example.mp3"></audio>
    
    <button id="A" class="button">ON</button>
    </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="st hidden" id="st2">
    <p>
    <audio id="audio2" src="example.mp3"></audio>
    
    <button id="B" class="button">ON</button>
    </p>
    </div>


</body>


<!--Controls the Drop Down Menu-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#station').on('change', function(){
        var theVal = $(this).val();
        $('.st').addClass('hidden');
        $('.st#st' + theVal).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
</script>

<!--Displays the error message if the audio file is not found and gives the option to reload the page.-->

<div id="dwnB" class="down">

<script>
$("#audio2").on("error", function(e) {
document.getElementById("B").outerHTML = '<div id="dwnB" class="down" align="center" onclick="location.reload();"><h2><b>The Audio File Could not be found.</h2> Please try again later.<br> Tap anywhere on this message to reload and try again.</b></div>';
        
});
</script>
</div>

<!--This script reloads the page and is tied to the above script-->

<script>
const reloadtButton = document.querySelector("#reload");
// Reload everything:
function reload() {
    reload = location.reload();
}
// Event listeners for reload
reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload, false);
</script>

</html>
```

I `get this when i run the snippet.`

```
Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: reloadButton is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 123,
  "colno": 1
}
```

Remember, Reload button **is not in the body of the page** but is in the script part of the page and only displays if there's an error. Even though button A in the first menu option should error as well. I did not write a script for it to do that so you can see what it looks like with out the error.

Here is the script for the reload button.

```
<!--Displays the error message if the audio file is not found and gives the option to reload the page. The entire error message is the reload button.-->

<div id="dwnB" class="down">

<script>
$("#audio2").on("error", function(e) {
document.getElementById("B").outerHTML = '<div id="dwnB" class="down" align="center" onclick="location.reload();"><h2><b>The Audio File Could not be found.</h2> Please try again later.<br> Tap anywhere on this message to reload and try again.</b></div>';
        
});
</script>
</div>

<!--This script reloads the page and is tied to the above script-->

<script>
const reloadtButton = document.querySelector("#reload");
// Reload everything:
function reload() {
    reload = location.reload();
}
// Event listeners for reload
reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload, false);
</script>
```

Reloading in the snippet causes the page to go blank. But if you run the code and reload somewhere else it displays as if you haven't chosen a menu option yet.

I don't know where "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js", is coming from as I don't see that in my code.

**How can I get to to stay on the current selected menu option after the reload button is clicked?**

Answer (score 1):

1. `const reloadButton = document.querySelector("#reload");` 
   As there is no element with id reload, reloadButton value is null
2. `reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload, false);` 
   As you now know that reloadButton is null, event cannot be attached

Instead of only creating the error body, add the reload button and then add an event, on this new reload button, refer code given below:

```js
$('#audio2').on('error', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('B').outerHTML = '<div id="dwnB" class="down" align="center" onclick="location.reload();"><h2><b>The Audio File Could not be found.</h2> Please try again later.<br> Tap anywhere on this message to reload and try again.</b><br><button class="reload">Reload</button> </div>';
    
    //once element with id 'dwnB' is created find the Reload Button
    let newReloadButton = document.querySelector("#dwnB .reload");
    newReloadButton.addEventListener('click', reload, false);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#station').on('change', function () {
        let value = $(this).val();
        $('.st').addClass('hidden');
        $('.st#st' + value).removeClass('hidden');

        //store your latest value in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('station', value);
    });
    
    //fetch the old value from localStorage
    let oldStation = localStorage.getItem('station');
    
    //set station value as per stored value
    if (oldStation) {
        $('#station').val(oldStation).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you created the New Reload Button, no need of this lines

1. `const reloadButton = document.querySelector("#reload");`
2. `reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload, false);`

Note: No need to add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` as you are using `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. The page resets to it's default view instead of staying on the page the user chose from the drop down menu. 

Also <button class="reload">Reload</button> is not needed in the code as the entire error message is a reload button.

Also your code snippet doesn't work either.